# KeyCloak Admin Functionality in Python

Tags: python, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Am trying to access Keycloak Admin for getting the user information with following code. Am getting 403 error while executing any GET commands.Can anyone help or have seen this in error. Am getting 'None' when am priniting, print(keycloak_admin1.get_token()).

```
from keycloak import keycloak_admin
keycloak_admin1 = keycloak_admin.KeycloakAdmin(server_url=endpoint,username=username, password=password,realm_name=realmname,client_id= clientid,client_secret_key=clientsecret,verify= True)
print(keycloak_admin1.realm_name)
print(keycloak_admin1.token)

# User counter
count_users = keycloak_admin1.users_count()
getusers = keycloak_admin1.get_user()
print(count_users)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Keycloak API's and it resolved my issue. Still not sure why python.keycloak package not working. So marking this issue done.

Comment: Hello @rakesh gupta, can you give a short description of what you have done to resolve? thanks

Comment: We went API's route, as  python.keycloak package was not working. We called the Login API to get the acces token and then used that token to access users attrbute. Let me know for any more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using both client secret and username password... Is this voluntary?

Another nice library is [mantelo](https://mantelo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It provides the same authentication mechanisms as python-keycloak, but only wraps the HTTP calls (instead of re-implementing them). It means you have "full/raw" access to the Admin API, but using Python-styled code.

In your case:

```py
from mantelo import KeycloakAdmin

# We assume the server is running on localhost:9090
# and the admin user is "admin" with password "admin"
c = KeycloakAdmin.from_username_password(
    server_url=endpoint, # e.g. "http://localhost:8080"
    realm_name=realm, # e.g. "master"
    client_id=client, # e.g. "admin-cli"
    username=user,
    password=pass,
)

# get number of users
c.users.count.get()

# get the users
c.users.get()
```

Example response for `c.users.get()`:

```py
[{'id': '8d83ecda-766d-4382-8f3a-4c5ac1962961',
  'username': 'constant',
  'firstName': 'Jasper',
  'lastName': 'Fforde',
  'email': 'j@f.uk',
  'emailVerified': True,
  'createdTimestamp': 1710273159287,
  'enabled': True,
  'totp': False,
  'disableableCredentialTypes': [],
  'requiredActions': [],
  'notBefore': 0,
  'access': {'manageGroupMembership': True,
   'view': True,
   'mapRoles': True,
   'impersonate': False,
   'manage': True}}]
```